# Sample code to use cTakes AggregatePlaintextUMLSProcessor

Tags: java, uima, ctakes

I'm new to Java and UIMA, and I can't find a comprehensive sample to use the AggregatePlaintextUMLSProcessor from code and print results in a proper format.

I managed to run cTakes from command line and I see it's using FileWriterCasConsumer.xml to write the output, but I want to know what other formats can I get.

I'va got the code for apache-ctakes-3.2.2 and it's building on a windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Stock cTakes supports writing data to:

- XMI,
- CSV,
- Plain text and
- HTML files.

You could take a look at sub packages `org.apache.ctakes.core.cc.*` in the `ctakes-core` module.